# Create dynamic name for value in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How I can create dynamic name of object from my value in array? For example:

This is my code:

```
var data=[{"column":"1", "count":"1"},{"column":"2", "count":"2"},{"column":"3", "count":"3"}];
var data2=[{"column":"1", "count":"5"},{"column":"2", "count":"2"},{"column":"3", "count":"7"}];
var data3=[{"column":"1", "count":"9"},{"column":"2", "count":"6"},{"column":"3", "count":"1"}];

var obj=[];

for (i=0;i<data.length;++i)
    obj.push({date: data[i].column, count1: data[i].count});

for (i=0;i<data2.length;++i)
     obj[i].count2 = data[2].count;

for (i=0;i<data3.length;++i)
     obj[i].count3 = data3[i].count;

console.log(obj);
```

and this is link for jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4tnewxg/

As you can see in the example is part of "count 1", etc. You can do it in a dynamic way? For example, the for loop and taking advantage of the 'i'? Then the name would be a "count" + i " results:  " count1 "," count2 " etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are after something like this maybe?

```
var obj = {};
...
obj["count"+i] = ...
```

Comment: "obj[i].count+i" This is the problem. I can't write 'count+i' for new element from my array

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use an object actually.

Answer (score 2):

You Simply use concat Function

```
var obj=data.concat(data2,data3);
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.